# Set containing a set containing itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that for sets $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$, it is impossible that $x_0\in x_1\in\dots\in x_n\in x_0$.

I tried to prove this statement using induction. For $n=0$, this is clear to me, it follows immediately from the axiom of regularity. However, I even failed to prove this for $n=1$ so far. I thought I should again somehow use the axiom of regularity, as it appears to me that this is the only axiom with which one can disprove the existence of a set. Nevertheless, I am stuck, and I would appreciate any help in clearing things up.

Comment: Surely the set $\{x_0, \ldots, x_n\}$ violates the axiom of regularity?